# AngularJS follow up child logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following situation, I'm building a quiz and I have some questions and some questions have childrens, depending on what you answer I'm wating to display the question coresponding the answer.

For example:

> Question title:
>
> 1. Answer 1
>
>    - Another question with answers 1
> 2. Answer 2
>
>    - Another question with answers 2

So when you press Answer 1 you will see 'Another question with answers 1' or if you press Answer 2 you will see 'Another question with answers 2'

My app structure look like this:

```
 $scope.currentIndex = 0;
 $scope.questions = [{
        title: 'Question title',
        choices: ['Answer 1', 'Answer 2'],
        extra: {
            childs: [{
                link: 'answer-1',
                title: 'Another question with answers 1',
                choices: ['Some answer', 'Some answer 2']
            }, {
                link: 'answer-2',
                title: 'Another question with answers 2',
                choices: ['Some answer', 'Some answer 2']
            }]
        }
    }, {
        title: 'Simple question title',
        choices: ['Answer 1', 'Answer 2']
    }]
```

And in my Angular app I'm displaying the questions using:

```
ng-repeat="question in questions track by $index" ng-if="isCurrentQuestion($index)"
```

The `isCurrentQuestion()` function looks like this:

```
$scope.isCurrentQuestion = function(index) {
            return $scope.currentQuestion === index
        };
```

Each time I answer to a question I add +1 to $scope.currentIndex to display the next question.

The thing I dont understand is how to display child questions from (`question.extra.childs`) in my app?

Maybe my structure isint quite right but I'm open for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested ng-repeat approach for resolving your requirement.

```
    <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
         // Do your logic here
        // use ng-if for your condition, if its true it will show your child elements
        <div ng-if="question.condition" ng-repeat="extraquestions in question.extra.childs">
       // Do your logic here
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How can I display the extra question just If I choose answer-1 for example?

Comment: @Hiero I have updated the answer, you can see it. its quite simple

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding another ng-repeat inside the current one like

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions track by $index" ng-if="isCurrentQuestion($index)">
     .......
    <div ng-repeat="extraquestions in question.extra.childs">
       .......
    </div>
</div>
```